# Python3 - Byte read does not return expected value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently reading a file and attempting to compare a byte value to my test variables. My comparison is always false as I am not returning the expected value.

My code:

```
def grey(self, varexec):
offsets = [0x388e93]
write = b'\x02'

test1 = b'\x02'
test2 = b'\x30'
test3 = b'\x10'
test4 = b'\x00'

for offset in offsets:
    with open(varexec, 'rb') as offsetwriter:
        offsetwriter.seek(offset)
        offsetwriter.seek(6,1)
        print(offsetwriter.read(2))
```

I expect the print(offsetwriter.read(2)) to return 
    b'\x14' 
as per the below but it doesn't. Without this I cannot use an if statement as it will always return false and thus lead to else.

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00788E93  |.  6A 01         PUSH 1                                   ; |Arg8 = 1
00788E95  |.  6A 0C         PUSH 0C                                  ; |Arg7 = 0C
00788E97  |.  51            PUSH ECX                                 ; |Arg6
00788E98  |.  8D50 14       LEA EDX,[EAX+14]                         ; |
00788E9B  |.  6A 30         PUSH 30                                  ; |Arg5 = 30
00788E9D  |.  52            PUSH EDX                                 ; |Arg4
00788E9E  |.  68 0C030000   PUSH 30C                                 ; |Arg3 = 30C
00788EA3  |.  50            PUSH EAX                                 ; |Arg2 => [LOCAL.1455]
00788EA4  |.  68 8F020000   PUSH 28F                                 ; |Arg1 = 28F
```

When I run my script I get:

```
b'P\x14'
```

Answer (score 1):

"P" is "\x50". You're off by 1. Also, "\x14" is 1 byte and you're reading 2.